# Running a simulation: replications or bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, simulation

I draw $n$ iid random draws from a univariate Gaussian distribution. My goal is to estimate the density $f$ using a nonparametric density estimation approach. To add a measure of uncertainty, I want to compute confidence bands for my estimate. Now I wonder how I should do that. Since I know the true distribution, I could just resample $m$ times. Or should I keep one sample and do bootstrapping? If I didn't know the true distribution, bootstrapping would be clearly the way to go but since I know $f$, there may be a way to use that information for adding confidence bands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (non-parametric) bootstrap sample is just sampling from the empirical distribution.  So when you do what is most commonly called bootstrapping you are just simulating from an estimate of the population/distribution.

Parametric bootstrap involves sampling from a distribution that you believe represents the population or random procedure, your described simulation is therefore a parametric bootstrap.

So your 2 choices are not really that different, mostly different in name.  Which to use depends on what future situations you want to generalize to.

Comment: What still confuses me: I resample $m$ times, for example, from $\mathcal N(0,1)$, compute estimates $\hat f_i$, $i=1,2,\dots,m$ and construct confidence bands from the $\alpha/2$ and $1-\alpha/2$-quantile of the empirical distribution of the $\hat f$'s. It could now be the case that my actual estimator $\hat f$ is outside of the confidence region. How do I ensure that the estimator is inside? Thank you for your reply

Comment: The very point of confidence bands is that not every realisation is inside. Even "worse", the definition of a confidence band of functions is rather unclear as should it impose for the entire function to stay within the band?

Comment: That's how I understand a pointwise (maybe I should have added that detail) confidence interval: the function stays within the band.